# Basic Form Validation Check Number?

Tags: php

In this script I am checking if fields are not empty and email address is syntactically correct. How to add a text input at the bottom of my form for a basic sum question, e.g. `(2+5)=` I want to add a validation element to my current script to check if this equals 7.

```
if (empty($name) || empty($phone) || empty($email) || empty($enquiry))
{
    echo "    * Sorry all fields are required.";
}
elseif(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)) 
{
    print "<p>Sorry the email address you entered looks like it's invalid.</p>";
}
else
{
    mail($to, $sub, $mes, $headers);
    print "<p>Thank you ".$name." for contacting us.<br /><br />We will be in touch shortly.</p>"; 
}
```

Comment: what you have tried to add sum of two numbers.

Comment: you can create basic math with random() for example rand()*100%10 + rand()*100%10 and save it in session. Then you can echo this equatation and in validation check the result with sesion. Have you considered recaptcha?

Comment: then.. `elseif($num!=$_SESSION['rand1']+$_SESSION['$rand2']) { print 'supplied number is wrong'; }`

Comment: I haven't tried to add anything yet as not great with PHP.

Comment: Put some code of your form and how it's displayed. Is it MVC or just simple php?

Comment: Check my answer and fit it to your needs.

Comment: This isn't safe as it's easy to code a script that reads the equation and calculates it. Use advanced image captcha's instead.

Comment: I agree with @HamZaDzCyberDeV you'd better use for example google's recaptcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to validate a static sum, e.g. you know it is always going to be **( 2 + 5 ) = 7**

Then you could just write a simple function to check the posted value.

```
// this being your posted value;
$validate = 7; 

function SumCheck($value){

    if ( 2 + 5 == $value ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then change your initial line to;

```
if (empty($name) || empty($phone) || empty($email) || empty($enquiry) || !SumCheck($validate))
```

However, I would suggest using RECAPTCHA as **Robert Podwika** has suggested.

Comment: It's so insecure.. No sense even in putting such validation. There is no randomness in this solution.

Comment: Simple validation against primitive bots. Not sure how complex bots would fare.

Comment: But yeah, I agree and should use ReCaptcha.

Answer (score 1):

1 If your session is not started use in the very first line

```
session_start();
```

2  Before form is shown. Add this code. Also remember that session start must be also in file where validation is.

```
 $numa =  rand(1,5);
 $numb =  rand(0,4);
 $_SESSION['valid_res'] = $numa+$numb;

  echo "<p>To submit form please solve this equatation $numa + $numb = ?";
  echo '<input type="text name="result_val" />';
```

3 In validation functions you should check

```
  if(intval($_POST['resul_val']) != $_SESSION['valid_res'])
  {
     echo "sorry you put wrong result in validation form";
  }
```

However, if I were you I'd use [RECAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: I think this is another debate, but such question/answer verifications are safer than captchas, supposing they are various enough and based on a strong randomness.

Comment: It's not randomness it's always pseudorandomness. Best solution for me is to put such equatation on image which is hard to be read by computer software.

Comment: I agree. Using images always adds a degree of difficulty for reversing. Equation on image is a good comprise. Another alternative is image containing text like "Enter the forth word of this sentence".
Concerning randomness, that's true there is no real randomness but some implementations are better than others.

Comment: I liked captcha where there was question "how many black cats are in the picture?" :)

Comment: Thanks Robert, RECAPTCHA is my preferred option but this is a very basic contact form for a site so don't need anything ultra secure.