# jQuery Cookie Age Verification?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I'm working on a beer site and trying to get it to go to an age verification page when the site loads using jQuery Cookie.

The age page has a simple Yes to accept the cookie and No to take you away from the site and my code is:

```
if(!$.cookie('legal-age')){
    window.location = '/age-verify/';
}

// Button
$("a#v-yes").click(function() {
    $.cookie('legal-age','yes', {expires: 7, path: '/'});
    window.location = '/';
    return false;
});
```

The problem I'm having is when the site loads it goes to the requested page but keeps refreshing over and over.

Any idea how to make it go to that page and just stay without refreshing?

Thanks,

TJ.

Comment: It should be working really?!  Hard to see without an example.  Have you got a demo anywhere we can help debug?

Comment: Thanks for that but without being able to "fiddle" the javascript it's hard to properly debug, I strongly suspect it's because you're running the same script on the "age-verify" page and that the cookie (which hasn't been set yet at the point of landing at 'age-verify') is failing the if and sending it into an eternal loop. Have you tried my suggestions from below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have mistakenly included the same code on the page which you are redirecting to.

Make sure that you do not include

```
if(!$.cookie('legal-age')){
    window.location = '/age-verify/';
}
```

On the `age-verify` page, and just the button event handler.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was using the same included header for the site so was loading that script in on that page causing it to refresh.

Comment: Is this some sort of a stitch up? Both from Glasgow and troll other peoples answers!? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460835/basic-form-validation-check-number

Comment: @RobSchmuecker haha no, he is my brother and just sends me the links to his stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Cheers for your help @RobSchmuecker much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Changing `window.location` will reload the page.

try to change `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work it just opens the home page with the url amended to /#/age-verify/ and doesn't redirect to the /age-verify/ page.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your comment above to @Filip Bartuzi,

Try changing your first `if` to this or variant thereof depending on your paths etc.

```
if(typeof($.cookie('legal-age')) === 'undefined' && window.location.pathname != '/age-verify'){
    window.location = '/age-verify/';
}
```